# How to prevent printing of "debug path" in stdout?

Tags: terminal, debug, stdout

Sys Vers: ubuntu precise 12.04 LTS

I seem to have a config setting that forces an executable to log to stdout (or stderr) the current directory it walks through. All commands execute successfully though. To give you an example :

```
root@myserver:/# bzr whoami<br/>
debug path usr<br/>
debug path usr<br/>
debug path bin<br/>
debug path usr<br/>
debug path bin<br/>
debug path python<br/>
debug path python2.7<br/>
debug path usr<br/>
debug path usr<br/>
debug path bin<br/>
debug path usr<br/>
debug path bin<br/>
debug path python2.7<br/>
debug path Modules<br/>
debug path Setup.dist<br/>
debug path Modules<br/>
debug path Setup.local<br/>
debug path config<br/>
debug path Makefile<br/>
debug path pyconfig.h<br/>
debug path .local<br/>
```

Anyone has seen this and could point me in the right direction ?
Cheers.

Comment: Does this occur for non-python programs?

Comment: I think a little more context is necesssary. What's this "config setting" you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Hi folks and sorry for not being back earlier. 
Here is the answer from our server admin, who kindly fixed it for me:

> I moved /etc/update-modt.d/91-release-upgrade to  /home/myhomedir/,
>   since this script calls : /usr/lib/update-manager/release-upgrade-motd
>   the latter generating the debug lines. So my solution is only
>   cosmetic.

Basically, If I understand right, there is still some debug code in update manager. And The script doesn't execute when I log into my user account.
Correct me if I'm stating wrong.